# Cannot use lambda inside `onClick` method of a custom class in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I want to create a series of click listeners for `TextView`s.

```
private class ClickListener(setValue: (Int) -> (Unit), getValue: () -> (Int)) : View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val oldValue = getValue()
            val newValue = v?.text.toString().toInt()
            if (newValue != oldValue) {
                if (oldValue != 0) {
                    v?.isSelected = false
                    v?.clearFocus()
                } else {
                    v?.isSelected = true
                    v?.requestFocus()
                    setValue(newValue)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here I create a custom click listener with lambdas (setter and getter). I create lambdas in Fragment, where I set click listeners to `TextView`s.

I can call `setValue()` and `getValue()` inside a constructor (`init`), but cannot use it inside `onClick()`.

[image]

If I call `getValue2()`, I will get another error:

[image]

Comment: @StefanGolubović, of course. I showed an example, that `getValue()` is accessible, but raises error. If I invoke nonexistent method (`getValue2()`), it raises another error. Sorry, I changed a source code to remove `getValue2()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `getValue()` and `setValue()` as properties:

```
private class ClickListener(
    val setValue: (Int) -> Unit,
    val getValue: () -> Int
) : View.OnClickListener {
```